# how can [if IE 6] can be taken by IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, conditional-comments

I am adding an aditional stylesheet for IE6

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
        <link href="../../nCss/comunHome_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

but is affecting to IE7 aswell,

edit-

even with

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <link href="../../nCss/comunHome_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Any idea why?

-edit2-

Also, with

```
    function isIE()
                // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
                // (indicating the use of another browser).
                {
                  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
                  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                  {
                    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
                    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
                    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
                  }
                  return rv;
                }
alert(isIE());
```

it outputs 7...

Comment: can you show us this in action? it doesn't sound right. a demo page to show it happening might help us work out what's going on.

Comment: try adding an IE6 conditional comment in the body but output a bit of text and see if that appears as well. Also try removing the stylesheet link entirely, does the issue remain (i.e. is it being loaded elsewhere as well)?

Comment: I am seeing it red in IE7 here http://jsfiddle.net/FXwxa/5/

Comment: Looks fine to me in IETester... what are you using to test, a real IE6 and IE7 browser?

Comment: looks fine to me in IE8 (in IE7 standards mode) and in a real IE7...

Comment: I use native IE7 and portable IE6

Comment: I would be concerned that portable IE6 was interfering somehow, I had issues (cross contamination I called them!) when using multiple IEs before. Does this http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/Q3fAg/ say you are using IE7 and do you get any orange text?

Comment: in portable6 i see it orange and 6. in native ie7 i see red and 7 (and both texts of mine: red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an option for IE 7 aswell?

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
<![endif]-->
```

Hmm I suppose you could use if and if !

Example usage IF I think this should work..

```
<!--[if (IE 6)&(!IE 7)]>
```

Comment: mmmm... i rather not to do that since IE7is using common styles, only need to hack ie6

Answer (score 1):

Try `<!--[if lt IE 7]>`, also test browser version with some js plugin to be sure that you are working on IE6 not IE7