# IE7 thinks it is IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements, conditional-comments

I'm trying to use conditional comments to hack IE7 into behaving like a real browser.

But the last few days, IE7 is ignoring conditionals referencing it, and responding only to conditionals targeting IE8.

My header has:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

...

The conditionals are:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ieHacks.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Which is NOT recognized in either IE7 or 8.  But if it's

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ieHacks.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then the stylesheet is rendered in both IE7 and IE8.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Sounds like a strange problem. Do you have a live example?

Comment: I don't have IE to test with, but have you tried removing the space between `IE` and `8`? (This is pure speculation and a wild guess, of course.)

Comment: @David Thomas: The space is supposed to be there, oddly enough.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks! (I had assumed so, but wasn't sure...) =)

Comment: One thing that came to my mind is that IE7 could begin being influenced by X-UA-Compatible header (it might be caused by some update or so); try removing it. However, I think it's more likely a caching issue or something like this. Try with new HTML document.

Comment: Heh, here's a related question from two weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912915/how-can-if-ie-6-can-be-taken-by-ie7 Apparently IE7 can't even find its way around conditional comments.

Comment: Can I ask how you are testing the different versions?  Separate PCs, virtual machines, IETester or IE8 or 9's dev tools switched to compatibility mode / older documenyts modes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with IE8 not reading the IE stylesheet, so now I prefer to add a class for IE on my main stylesheet. It is easier to maintain code with one stylesheet anyway. Paul Irish [explains it better](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) but basically you put this:

```
<!--[if IE]> <html class="ie"> <![endif]-->
```

where your conditional stylesheet link was and then in your css you add the ie class for every IE-specific change you need. So let's say your padding is normally 6px but for IE you need it to be 4px, your css for that div would look like:

```
.someClass {padding: 6px;}
.ie .someClass {padding: 4px;}
```

Comment: I'd add the class to the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a CSS hack to target IE7 only from within your main stylesheet:

```
*:first-child+html { /* Apply IE7-only CSS here */ }
```